# Science is fun, but rhyme takes time

Tags: riddle, science

In sixty seven, I was first found
By a couple of scientists poking around

It was quite a novelty they did detect
Little green men might cause the effect

They stuffed me in a bag for a catchy new name
Soon cousins were found, but we're not all the same

The theories abound on what makes us tick,
If you know what I am, then answer now, quick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are:

> A [Pulsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar#Discovery)

Reasoning:
In sixty seven, I was first found
By a couple of scientists poking around

> Discovered in 1967

It was quite a novelty they did detect

> It was a novel kind of star at the time

Little green men might cause the effect

> nicknamed little green men

They stuffed me in a bag for a catchy new name

> Pulsar, the new name, is a portmanteau of pulsating star so maybe that is what this clue means

Soon cousins were found, but we're not all the same

> Later found pulsars from different sources

The theories abound on what makes us tick,

> There are many theories on how they work maybe?

If you know what I am, then answer now, quick!

> A pulsar